# Is it possible to get a pointer of a list member?

Tags: python, pointers, python-3.4

I saw some related questions and I think my question is still unanswered. How can I get a pointer (reference) to the list member? Say, I have:

```
>>> a = [None]
>>> d = a[0]
>>> d = 3
```

I expect to get:

```
>>> a
[3] # But I get [None] of course.
```

Is it possible in Python at all? Or how can I implement that?

**UPDATE**

My final goal is to change the **source**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You can't store a reference to a location in a list and try to update it later through assignment.

If you want to implement a work-around, then you might want to use a closure to capture a reference to the desired index in your list. Here's an example:

```
# Here's my list
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Save a reference to the list using a function to close over it
def myref(x): mylist[1] = x

# Update the referenced value to 7
myref(7)

# mylist is now [1, 7, 3, 4]
print mylist
```

You're stuck using the `myref(7)` syntax rather than `myref = 7` syntax since there's no way to overload the assignment operator in Python, but I think that will work for you.

In your comment on one of the other answers you mentioned that you're actually dealing with an n-dimensional list, and you want to save a reference so that you can update it later when the indices aren't in scope. This works nicely for that case as well. Here's an example:

```
# My 3D list
list3D = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]

# Find 
def findEntry(data, x):
    for i, page in enumerate(data):
        for j, row in enumerate(page):
            for k, col in enumerate(row):
                if col == x:
                    def myref(y): data[i][j][k] = y
                    return myref

# Get a reference to the first cell containing 4
updater = findEntry(list3D, 4)

# Update that cell to be 44 instead
updater(44)

# list3D is now [[[1, 2], [3, 44]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
print list3D
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear. Yeah, this is what I have right now (with lambdas). With pointers my code would be more compact...

Comment: @Necronomicron - You did it with lambdas? When I was putting together the example I _tried_ using lambdas, but then I realized you can't do an assignment in a lambda, so I switched to `def` instead.

Comment: Sorry, lambdas **and** functions. Of course we can't do assignments in lambdas. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better style to use a ref cell, than to use a pointer. Pointers are a distant concept from the point-of-view of python. You can make a cheap ref cell from a list.

```
pointer = [3]
pointer[0] = 5 #change value of ref cell
pointer[0] #get value of ref cell
```

Comment: So a list of these (as in the original question) would really be a list of lists, e.g. `a = [[None]]`.

Comment: It is a simple call by index. I have N-dimensional array where I need a pointer to a certain member, because indices are unavailable 'right now'. It hard to explain and it's really doesn't matter right now.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in class

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> a = [A()]
>>> a[0]
<__main__.A object at 0x1004ad850>
>>> a[0].x = 5
>>> a
[<__main__.A object at 0x1004ad850>]
>>> b = a[0]
>>> b.x
5
>>> b.x = 6
>>> a[0].x
6
```

Comment: Yeah, but array was `a = [None]`. And anyway wrapping in my case make it worse.

Comment: Still valid, wrap the None in a class.